# Can anyone give me a hint how to start this one...

Tags: probability-distributions

If the variance of the random variable X exists, show that $\mathbf{E}(X^2)≥[\mathbf{E}(X)]^2$. I don't know how to start, so any hint is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $(X - \mathbf{E}X) ^ 2 =  $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(X - \mathbf{E}X) ^ 2 = X^2 - 2X \mathbf{E}X + \mathbf{E}X^2$. This quantity is nonnegative. Taking expectations yeld
$$0 \leq \mathbf{E}\big[(X - \mathbf{E}X)^2 \big] = \mathbf{E}[X^2] - 2\mathbf{E}X \mathbf{E}X + (\mathbf{E}X)^2 = \mathbf{E}[X^2] - (\mathbf{E}X)^2$$ 
wich is what you wanted.